# Add text to one column of data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to add a text only to one column.

I tried the following(here as an example):

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
addMe <- c('test1','test2','test3')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
dat <- data.frame(employee, salary, addMe)

dat[] <- lapply(dat$addMe, function(x) paste(' Please delete this col!', x))
```

However, my result frame looks like the following:

```
     employee                            salary                          addMe
1    Please delete this col! John Doe    Please delete this col! 21000   Please delete this col! test1
2    Please delete this col! Peter Gynn  Please delete this col! 23400   Please delete this col! test2
3    Please delete this col! Jolie Hope  Please delete this col! 26800   Please delete this col! test3
```

However I would like to have as a result:

```
    employee      salary        addMe
1   John Doe      21000         Please delete this col! test1
2   Peter Gynn    23400         Please delete this col! test2
3   Jolie Hope    26800         Please delete this col! test3
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: paste is vectorized already. As in `paste('message', dat$addMe)`

Comment: The `lapply` returns a list, and substitutes the whole data frame with that list. You need the `sapply`

Comment: OP, Your result frame does not match the actual result.

Comment: Ha. That would explain it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just run

```
dat$addMe <- paste0("Please delete this col! ", dat$addMe)
```

in place of your lapply line.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `sapply`, not the `lapply`:

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
addMe <- c('test1','test2','test3')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
dat <- data.frame(employee, salary, addMe)


dat$addMe <- sapply(dat$addMe, function(x) paste(' Please delete this col!', x))

dat
```

Yielding:

```
> dat
    employee salary                          addMe
1   John Doe  21000  Please delete this col! test1
2 Peter Gynn  23400  Please delete this col! test2
3 Jolie Hope  26800  Please delete this col! test3
```

Comment: You do not need an apply function at all

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I am also trying to follow his thought process here. Not completely clear yet what the `lapply` was doing.